# How to create a HTML and CSS "Try it yourself" Editor

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know there are a number of "Try It Yourself" JavaScript editors, such as W3School's Try It editor, JSBin, and JSFiddle.

I'm developing a graphical Html and CSS library that I'd like to let people try out from my own site (I want to be able to display the result on the same page like the other editors). I have looked online for help on creating one of these and I can't seem to find any information. I tried to piece something together so If someone could look over that it would be appreciated. I would really like to create a page that has a box for html and another box for css, then have a button that executes the page, then display the information on the right hand of the page. Here is the code that I have so far, and hopefully someone can help me out. Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<form method="post" action="tryit.php" target="result">
<button>Try it</button>
<table>
<tr>
    <td><textarea name="html"></textarea></td>
    <td><textarea name="css"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>

    <td><iframe name="result"></iframe></td>
</tr>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
    <?php echo $_POST["html"]; ?>
    <?php echo file_get_contents('css contents')?>
</style>
</script>
 </head>
<body>
<?php echo file_get_contents('html contents')?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to do the job of a browser that's not that easy !

Comment: be careful when you let people submit code... but, just use javascript to load whatever dynamically (html, css).  this is a really open ended question and there are many ways to go about it... what specifically are you having problems doing right now?

Comment: Use `echo $_POST["html"];` and php will write the received html code into the document.

Comment: Where do I insert this into my code? And i updated my code and took a little bit of unnecessary code out.

Comment: @gloomy.penguin Right now when I click try it, it just shows me a picture of the same webpage in the box thats supposed to display the html and css that the user inputs

Comment: if you post from a form with an element named `html` (requires a submit button click and page load), add to your code above, anywhere in there... `<?php echo $_POST["html"]; ?>` and it will dump whatever was sent.  you might need to (un)escape or (de)code things.  I'm not sure.  if you want it instant and dynamic, use javascript.

Comment: @gloomy.penguin Where would you put this statement in my code? because I am putting it in the body tags but all it does is display the same webpage in a box instead of displaying the html and css code that the user inputs

Comment: your tags are all messed up... your `</form>` is outside of your `</body>`

Comment: @gloomy.penguin Is that better? it still doesnt work for me though so something isnt right

Comment: @PHPglue So i should add these statements into my code?

Comment: @deKajoo that's not true, he doesn't have to do most of the work, actually

Comment: you don't need php for this

Comment: I agree, you would use JavaScript.

Comment: May I ask why this is on hold? It appears to meet the requirements http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic there

Comment: Have you seen the minimalist JS-only solution that is just 158 bytes long: http://xem.github.io/miniCodeEditor/ ?

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn No I havent, but javascript would be perfect to help me make this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have PHP on this computer so I can't test anything... this can give you the basic idea, though.  And it's been about a year since I touched PHP... there are probably syntax errors.  Sorry.  HTML is not my best language, either.

note: i wrote this like it was submitting to itself... kind of.

```
<html>
   <body>
      <?php if (!isset($_POST['html']) or empty($_POST['html'])) { ?>
               <form method="post" action="tryit.php">
                  <table>
                     <tr><td><textarea name="html"></textarea></td></tr>
                  </table>
                  <input type="submit" value="Try It">
               </form>
      <?php } 
      else  { echo $_POST['html']; } ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

---

i like this better (**note:** it does use jquery... i can provide js only if you really want):

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <style> textarea { width: 400px; } </style>
   </head>
   <body> 
      <form id='tryitform' method="post" action="tryit.php">
         <table>
            <tr><td><textarea name="html"><b>hello!</b></textarea></td></tr>

            <!-- tr><td><textarea name="html"><script>window.location = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ";</script></textarea></td></tr -->

            <tr><td><textarea name="css">body { background-color: #ccc; }</textarea></td></tr>
         </table>
         <input type="submit" value="Try It">
      </form> 
      <div id='htmlcontent'></div>
   </body>
</html>

<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $('#tryitform').submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); 
      $('#htmlcontent').html( $(':input[name=html]').val() );
      $('head').append( '<style>' + $(':input[name=css]').val() + '</style>' ); 
   }); 
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: It's possible without php to do what he/she wants, so I'd avoid this approach

Comment: @Markasoftware How would I do it a different way?

Comment: I was gonna post an answer, but it's closed...I'll try to edit it then maybe re-open it and post an answer

Comment: Why was this closed? What did I do wrong lol. I am just looking for help.

Comment: @Markasoftware - yeah... i said js in the comments up there but it looked like he really wanted php..?  idk.

Comment: @johnnyDepp - i updated my answer with a working jquery example. just save it in a file on your desktop `whatever.html` and click stuff.

Comment: @johnnyDepp it's probably closed because you didn't show any research effort, and questions like this are generally looked down upon (questions about "How do I do this" instead of a clear, specific problem). If you edit the question to show what you have tried and what you know about this so far, there's a chance (albeit a small one) that this'll be re-opened

Comment: @gloomy.penguin Thanks a lot it works, just wondering what is the <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> line for? And could you write the program without it?

Comment: I said what it is for.  Get your question re-opened (by making it better... see meta, help or faq) and I will write it with straight js.

Comment: Oh is it for jquery? Do you have to have this line in for the program to work?

Comment: @gloomy.penguin okay Ill try my best, but marasoftware said theres a small chance that it will be reopened

Comment: just google it then... google the pure js approach for what i did in jquery.  override a submit button.  get the value inside a text area.  add html to an existing div.  add css to the head.

Comment: okay ill try and look it up. Thanks for the help, and I edited my question to try and get it unlocked. Thanks again

Comment: @johnnyDepp - omg, you just took my answer and posted it as your own....??  wtf.  lol...

Comment: Um what else was I supposed to do

Comment: fix the question to make it better... fix **your** question.  [FAQ on good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [the SO blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/) and [the link provided in the closed text above](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [found on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260649/623952)